# How do you test if an observable is retried X times when failing?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, xctest

I've got an observable that I need to retry a few times if it failed. And I'm currently trying to unit test it. So far I have done this and it failed and always returned 1 instead of 11 times:

```
func testSetCreated_ShouldRetry10Times_BeforeStopping() throws {
    let setCreatedProvider: (String, String) -> Single<ResponseData> = { (_, _) in
        return .error(RxCocoaURLError.unknown)
    }
    let statusHandler = createConsultationHandler(setCreatedProvider: setCreatedProvider)

    var setCreatedEmitCount = 0
    statusHandler.setCreated(consultationId: .random(length: 24))
        .subscribe(onError: { _ in
            setCreatedEmitCount += 1
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    sleep(10)
    XCTAssertEqual(11, setCreatedEmitCount)
}
```

So, how exactly can I test that this will be called max 11 times if failing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, understand that an Observable will only ever emit a *single* error event. There is no way to get your test to pass as it stands.

However, the following will pass although I'm not sure why you name the function `10Times` when you are checking to see if it made 11 attempts.

```swift
class rx_sandboxTests: XCTestCase {

    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func testSetCreated_ShouldRetry10Times_BeforeStopping() throws {
        var setCreatedEmitCount = 0
        let setCreatedProvider: (String, String) -> Single<ResponseData> = { (_, _) in
            setCreatedEmitCount += 1
            return .error(RxCocoaURLError.unknown)
        }
        let statusHandler = createConsultationHandler(setCreatedProvider: setCreatedProvider)

        statusHandler.setCreated(consultationId: .random(length: 24))
            .subscribe()
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        XCTAssertEqual(11, setCreatedEmitCount)
    }
}

func createConsultationHandler(setCreatedProvider: @escaping (String, String) -> Single<ResponseData>) -> ConsultationHandler {
    return ConsultationHandler(setCreatedProvider: setCreatedProvider)
}

struct ConsultationHandler {
    private let createdProvider: (String, String) -> Single<ResponseData>
    init(setCreatedProvider: @escaping (String, String) -> Single<ResponseData>) {
        self.createdProvider = setCreatedProvider
    }
    func setCreated(consultationId: String) -> Observable<ResponseData> {
        return Observable.just(())
            .flatMap { [createdProvider] in createdProvider("hello", "world") }
            .retry(11)
    }
}
struct ResponseData { }
enum RxCocoaURLError: Error { case unknown }
extension String {
    static func random(length: Int) -> String {
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah right. The one inside the flatmap is the one that will be called multiple times, not the `setCreated()` observable. My bad. And about why I assert it with the value 11, I was thinking that it was 1 initial error + 10 retries.